# добавление модуля в менеджер модулей (раздел сайт)

Tags: joomla

Здравствуйте , подскажите пожалуйста как добавить в менеджер модулей новый, тип модуля,
я пробовал просто создать папку с именем нового типа в корневой папке /modules
прописав все не обходимые вещи в файлах название_модуля.xml и .php
однако ни нового модуля ни типа модулей не появилось. Подскажи пожалуйста как это правильно делается.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил как и говорилось выше установкой через стандартный загрузчик, а в хмл вместо нужно директории сайт было написано администратор.

Answer (score 0):

а через установку модулей не пробовал? Если не получается то проверяй путь расположения твоего модуля, просмотри XML что ты там по написал. Ничего не помогло, за архивируй в zip сжатие максимальное, и попробуй поставить.

Comment: пробовал, модуль добавляется в административную часть, нужно в общею (сайт)